# How to retain data on server side during multiple Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, javabeans

From the client side (JS), I am doing multiple AJAX calls one by one, when
   user clicks on a button.  On the server side (JAVA), once I receive
   parameters from the AJAX call, I am performing some business logic &
   sending the processed data to client-side through JSP. But now I need to store that processed data throughout all the ajax calls.

Explaining my new requirement -

1) 1st AJAX call - Receive parameters & store the
   processed output in some object let's name it "processedData".

2) 2nd AJAX call - Receive parameters & "append" the processed output in
   "processedData" object

Continue doing this till n-1 calls

3) nth AJAX call - Use "processedData" object to determine the output of this
   (final) AJAX call.

So, I want to retain processedData object till all the AJAX calls are completed. Is this possible in JAVA?

Comment: On client side why not return the data you wish to continue to send, append to next ajax call and send it.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to store the data some where 
then

1. you will need to give the first request unique id like (UUId) and
   return the UUId to the client and the client store the id in the
   cookies or somewhere.
2. then each request will have the id in the query string or in the
   request header.
3. then you back-end will query all previous requests with the
   UUId(from the data store).
4. the last request will have the UUID and a flag 'last' and your
   back-end will do the rest.

i hope this helps you.